# PHP Update only updates last record

Tags: php, sql

I have a form where the user input is used  and compared with the same value on the database and if the input is invalid it rejects and does not update.

When the user input is correct the form thens forwards it and my code finds the corresponding ID from that input and then update it.

But so far what this does is update the last record.

Here's my code :

I do apologize it's a bit long so please bear with it. I am still a student and a total noob.

```
require("connect.php");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM driver LEFT JOIN vehicle ON driver.vehicle_id = vehicle.vehicle_id");
while($driverlist = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

                            $vehiclestatus = $driverlist['v_status'];
                            $driver = $driverlist['d_fname'];
                            $driver_id =$driverlist['driver_id'];
                            $v_model = $driverlist['v_model'];
                            $plate_number = $driverlist['plate_number'];
                            $vehicleid = $driverlist['vehicle_id'];
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>'.$driver.'</td>';

                            echo '<td>'.$driver_id.'</td>';

                            echo '<td>'.$v_model.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$plate_number.'</td>';







                        echo '</tr>';
}









if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
    $vehicle_id = $_POST['vehicle_id'];
    $driverid = $_POST['driver_id'];

               require("connect.php");
                       mysql_query("UPDATE vehicle RIGHT JOIN driver ON vehicle.vehicle_id = driver.driver_id  SET v_status = '1'   WHERE driver.vehicle_id = '".$vehicle_id."' AND driver_id = '".$driverid."'")
                or die(mysql_error());

                   }

if(isset($_POST['update']))
                {
                   $vehicle_id = $_POST['vehicle_id'];
                   $driverid = $_POST['driver_id'];

                       require("connect.php");

                mysql_query("UPDATE vehicle RIGHT JOIN driver ON vehicle.vehicle_id = driver.driver_id SET v_status = '0' WHERE driver.vehicle_id = '".$vehicle_id."' AND driver_id = '".$driverid."'")
                or die(mysql_error());




                header('Location: drivers.php');
                }


if(!empty($_POST['registerbtn']))
{
    $driver = $_POST['driver'];
    require("connect.php");


                        $match_driver = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM driver WHERE d_fname = '$driver'");
                        $rows = mysql_num_rows($match_driver);






                        if($rows != 0)
                        {
                            while($row_driver = mysql_fetch_array($match_driver))
                            {


                                $a_fname = $row_driver[2];
                                $a_id = $row_driver[0];
                            }
                        }
                        error_reporting(0);
                        if($driver == $a_fname){

                        require("connect.php");

                        mysql_query("UPDATE trip_reservation SET driver_id = '".$a_id."' WHERE trip_id = '".$tripid."'");

                        //mysql_query("INSERT INTO trip_reservation (trip_id, driver_id) VALUES('".$tripid."', '".$a_id."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE trip_id = '".$tripid."'")or die(mysql_error());



                        echo "Driver Added Successfully";

                        }
                        else{
                            echo "The Driver is not found in the database <br>
                            Please input a valid Driver.";
                        }


}




else {
    echo $registerform;
    }
?>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.

Comment: and why connect more than 1 time?

Comment: is connecting more than 1 time an issue? I'm sorry i don't really know.

Comment: You should understand your codes before you write it.

Answer (score 0):

Why joining tables when updating records on a single table.
And secondly, you're comparing a WHERE clause on a table you're not even updating

Instead of this

```
"UPDATE vehicle RIGHT JOIN driver ON vehicle.vehicle_id = driver.driver_id SET v_status = '0' WHERE driver.vehicle_id = '".$vehicle_id."' AND driver_id = '".$driverid."'"
```

Do this

```
"UPDATE vehicle SET v_status = '0' WHERE id = '".$vehicle_id."' AND driver_id = '".$driverid."'"
```

This is assuming your vehicle table has a primary key field named **id** and a foreign key field to the drivers_table named **driver_id**

And yes, it should update JUST ONE RECORD